# How to add islice function to python program?

Tags: python, import, module, iterable

I am trying to use the islice function but am getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/gavinnachbar/Session 3 copy/all_in_one_almost.py", line 168, in <module>
    all_decisions.extend(islice(reader,4))
NameError: name 'islice' is not defined
```

I have imported itertools but am still getting the error, any idea why?

Comment: http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html

Answer (score 9, accepted):

... because you are trying to `import iterator`, which does not exist?

**Edit:**

Have you tried either

```
from itertools import islice
```

or

```
all_decisions.extend(itertools.islice(reader,4))
```

Comment: Whoops sorry, copied the wrong error message the correct one has been added now

Comment: Using itertools.islice works! For all python modules is it necessary to use that form to access a function?

Comment: @user2512696 Either that, or import it using the `from ... import ...` syntax that is shown.  In that case you wouldn't need the `itertools.` before `islice`

Answer (score 2):

**Q. I have imported itertools but am still getting the error, any idea why?**

**A.**  Yes.  When you `import itertools`, you need to write `itertools.islice` instead of just `islice`.